# Registering a class and getting instance of the returned model using DRYIOC

Tags: .net, inversion-of-control, dryioc

I want to register and get instance of current user in userviewmodel using DryIoc.Please how do i achieve this. This is the CurrentUserConfig class

```
public class CurrentUserConfig
{

    private IContainer _container;
    private UserViewModel _userViewModel;

    public CurrentUserConfig(IContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
        _userViewModel = new UserViewModel();
    }

    public UserViewModel GetCurrentUser()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name) && Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            if (_userViewModel == null || _userViewModel.UserId < 1)
            {
                try
                {
                    var repository = _container.Resolve<IUserRepository>();
                    _userViewModel = Task.Run(async () => await repository.GetUserByUsername(Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name)).Result;
                }
                catch (System.Exception ex)
                {
                    //return exception error;
                }
            }
        }

        return _userViewModel;
    }

}
```

This is what i want to achieve using DryIoc. This was done using  SimpleInjector

```
        var currentUserConfig = new CurrentUserConfig(container);
        container.RegisterSingleton(currentUserConfig);

        container.Register<UserViewModel>(() =>
        {
            var objCurrentUserConfig = container.GetInstance<CurrentUserConfig>();

            return currentUserConfig.GetCurrentUser();
        }, Lifestyle.Scoped);
```

Comment: Why do you resolving `var repository = _container.Resolve<IUserRepository>();` instead of just injecting `IUserRepository` into `CurrentUserConfig` ?

Comment: If i inject IUserRepository into CurrentUserConfig, I get the error  "Recursive dependency is detected when resolving
UserViewModel as parameter "user" <--recursive
  in singleton UserRepository: IUserRepository as parameter "userRepository"
  in singleton CurrentUserConfig
  in scoped UserViewModel as parameter "currentUser" <--recursive
  in scoped UserController."  Hence,reason why i am not injecting IUserRepository in the CurrentUserConfig class

Comment: What is the disadvantage of resolving in CurrentUserConfig @dadhi ?

Comment: Disadvantage is that you are relying on container as on service locator somewhere inside your method. The dependency to user repository is not evident, which may hide bugs and make things untestable. Given your case, when you move dependency to the surface (make it a parameter), you indeed found  that dependency is recursive. It may or may not be the error, but at least it is not a surprise.

Answer (score 1):

Direct translation would be:

```
var currentUserConfig = new CurrentUserConfig(container);
container.UseInstance(currentUserConfig);
container.RegisterDelegate<UserViewModel>(resolver =>
{ 
    var objCurrentUserConfig = resolver.Resolve<CurrentUserConfig>();
    return currentUserConfig.GetCurrentUser();
}, Reuse.InCurrentScope);
```

Alternatively you may register user config by type:

```
container.Register<CurrentUserConfig>(Reuse.Singleton);
container.RegisterDelegate<UserViewModel>(resolver => 
{ 
   var objCurrentUserConfig = resolver.Resolve<CurrentUserConfig>();
   return currentUserConfig.GetCurrentUser(); 
}, Reuse.InCurrentScope);
```

Note, that registering `IContainer` for user config is not required. DryIoc will automatically inject correctly scoped container instance.

There may be a further improvement to register user with DryIoc `Made.Of` construct. `Made.Of` enables registering with any instance or static class member returning the service. It is generally better than `RegisterDelegate` because DryIoc may analyse the service creation, and warn you about captive or recursive dependencies.

```
container.Register<CurrentUserConfig>(Reuse.Singleton);
container.Register<UserViewModel>(
    Made.Of(_ => ServiceInfo.Of<CurrentUserConfig>(), config => config.GetCurrentUser()),
    Reuse.InCurrentScope);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I thought i would need to pass the instance of IContainer to the constructor of CurrentUserConfig. And since i am not resolving my IUserRepository, it is no more needed.